# Escaping backslash when adding file path to local storage ?

Tags: html, file-upload, local-storage

I want to save a file path in local storage of chrome, but the js API escape the "\" character then I can't retrieve the file again. any suggestion to prevent escaping backslash when adding a file path to local storage?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't escape the backslash, here's a snippet from chrome's JS console session:

```
>>> localStorage["test"] = "C:\\test";
"C:\test"
>>> localStorage["test"]
"C:\test"
```

Try posting a testcase (for example using http://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates the problem -- a testcase is worth a thousand words.